# How to design project solution for webapi2 with angularjs project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am starting new project with angularjs with webapi. This project will be e-commerce site. There is iOS and Android app also. We are going to develop APIs so that Android and iOS team can consume our APIs. Also we are going to consume APIs using angularjs for web application. I need some inputs before starting project. I am planning to design separate solutions for APIs and my web application. I am using visual studio for development environment for front end. I am confused about which template should I use in vs2015 to develop front end? My front-end will contains angular js files,HTML pages and CSS files. Second point is there is a Arabic version of this website so I am storing all Arabic words in resource file. Where should I store my resource files? In API project or front end project? May I get some inputs to develop solution architecture? Also what is the standard way of angularjs project folder structure? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.